# How to change Current_TimeStamp in esql IIB

Tags: integration

current system time stamp be like `2019-12-10 16:34:20`

how to change to `2019/12/10 16:34:20`

hypan replace to forward slash

i wrote code like

```
SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.CompanyInfo.RequestDatetime = CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS CHARACTER FORMAT 'yyyy/MM/dd');
```

but its not working ...

Answer (score 1):

SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.CompanyInfo.RequestDatetime = CAST(CURRENT_DATE AS CHARACTER FORMAT 'yyyy/MM/dd') || ' ' || CAST(CURRENT_TIME AS CHARACTER FORMAT 'HH:mm:SS');

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).